# Java Regex match exact SSN pattern

Tags: java, regex

I want to capture exact SSN pattern DDD-DD-DDDD from the input string not the other pattern DDD-DD-DDDD-DDD

```
String line = " Hello my SSN : 111-22-3333-444 and another SSN: 333-56-3789" ;
    
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d{3}-\\d{2}-\\d{4}");
Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
while(m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group() );
}
```

I'm getting output as

```
111-22-3333
333-56-3789
```

Expected Output: `333-56-3789`

I tried adding `\b` boundaries still no luck

Comment: Add an anchor `\\d{3}-\\d{2}-\\d{4}$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
(?<!\d|\d[.-])\d{3}(?=([.-]))\1\d{2}\1\d{4}(?![.-]?\d)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JQEFzp/5). **Details**:

- `(?<!\d|\d[.-])` - no digit nor digit + `-` / `.` immediately to the left is allowed
- `\d{3}` - three digits
- `(?=([.-]))`  - a positive lookahead that captures the next char that must be `.` or `-`
- `\1` - same value as captured with the capturing group in the lookahead
- `\d{2}` - two diigits
- `\1` - same value as captured with the capturing group in the lookahead
- `\d{4}`  -  four digits
- `(?![.-]?\d)` - no `-` / `.` + digit or just digit is allowed immediately to the right of the current location.

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/88D4uy):

```
String line = "Hello my 1st SSN : 11.333.56.3788 , 2nd SSN: 333-56-3789 , 3rd SSN 333.56.3780" ;
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<!\\d|\\d[.-])\\d{3}(?=([.-]))\\1\\d{2}\\1\\d{4}(?![.-]?\\d)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
while(m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group() );
}
// => 333-56-3789 and 333.56.3780
```

Comment: the delimiter can be . or space, how to handle in the this command ?
(?<!\d|\d-)\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}(?!-?\d)

Comment: @Sadu You mean the "match" delimiters, *boundaries*? Then use `Pattern.compile("(?<![^.\\s])\\d{3}-\\d{2}-\\d{4}(?![^.\\s])")`. See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JQEFzp/2).

Comment: @ Wiktor.. 

Need to handle different delimiter in input
If my input is "Hello my 1st SSN : 11.333.56.3788 , 2nd SSN: 333-56-3789 , 3rd SSN 333.56.3780" 

My output should be 333-56-3789 & 333.56.3780.

Comment: @ Wiktor thanks a lot for helping me out. I was struggling for long time, you saved me. 

The above regex breaks some where, can't figure out. Please help..

Input:
1st Invalid-SSN : 11.111.11.1111 ,  2nd Valid-SSN: 222-22-2222 , 3rd Valid-SSN 333.33.3333 , 4th Valid-SSN:  444 44 4444 and 5th InValid-SSN : 555 55 55555 and 6th InValid-SSN : 666 66 6666 6
...................................
Expected Output: 
Valid-SSN: 222-22-2222
Valid-SSN: 333.33.3333 
Valid-SSN: 444 44 4444

Only SSN with (Hypen, Dot & Whitesapce) is allowed in 3-2-4 format

Comment: @Sadu You added a space, so add it, `Pattern.compile("(?<!\\d|\\d[.\\s-])\\d{3}(?=([.\\s-]))\\1\\d{2}\\1\\d{4}(?![.\\s-]?\\d)")`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/JQEFzp/6)

Comment: now we coded to capture SSN format DDD-DD-DDDD , I have requirement to capture another pattern DDD-DDD-DDD. When i add the similar code with a Pipe function it's not working. Please suggest.
(?<!\\d|\\d[.\\s-])\\d{3}(?=([.\\s-]))\\1\\d{2}\\1\\d{4}(?![.\\s-]?\\d) | (?<!\\d|\\d[.\\s-])\\d{3}(?=([.\\s-]))\\1\\d{3}\\1\\d{3}(?![.\\s-]?\\d)

Comment: @Sadu No, do not do that. You need to replace `\\d{4}` with `\\d{3,4}` to match three or four digits.

Comment: Perfect, You are genius.  it works fine. Will accept the solution........ I have couple of  requirements like the SSN user might enter in any format like 1234567-89 OR 12-3456789 OR 123-456789 OR 123456-789 OR 123-45-6789 OR 123-456-789..............if i use \\d{3,4} logic it will work for DDD-DD-DDDD & DDD-DDD-DDD.... But it won't work for DD-DDDDDDD & DDD-DDDDDD .. So i thought of using Pipe.. Please assist. The objective is to capture 9 digit SSN in any format.

Comment: @ Wiktor , how to merge the above regex logic for these SSN formats DD-DDDDDDD or DDD-DDDDDD or DDDDDDD-DD or DDDDDD-DDD.

Please assist

Comment: @Sadu See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JQEFzp/7).

Comment: @ Wiktor, I really thank you for you big help. You are awesome!!  I just did some small change to your code by removing ? from the below pattern. as its capturing 123456789 continuous number also in the input. Please review is it fine ? ........ Your Code:: \d{3}(?=([.\s-]?))\1?\d{2}\1?\d{4}   ------  Modified code:: \d{3}(?=([.\s-]))\1?\d{2}\1?\d{4}....... Also can i get explanation of your code

Comment: @ Wiktor.. Today i got one more requirement...is it possible to add extra logic to your code. I need to capture the SSN based on Tags provided............. Example ::: Input file ::> Hi i'm john my SSN is 123-45-6789 and my another 123-456789 is my wife SocialSec. My Son SS # is 12-3456789 and my daughter SSN# : 123456789 and Pin code 111-22-3333 ......... In the above example the Tags are : SSN,SocialSec,SS,SSN#... I need to find 4 valid SSN based on Tags before or After. Not the pincode one as it look like ssn but we should not capture it. Please assist.

Comment: @Sadu Removing `?` in `(?=([.\s-]?))` makes a delimiter obligatory at that location. If it is OK with you, if it fits your data, use it.

Comment: @Sadu The [requirement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64062737/java-regex-match-exact-ssn-pattern/64062773?noredirect=1#comment113316946_64062773) changes the question too much already. Please try something on your own, then - if you fail - post another question.

Comment: @ Wiktor, Sure will try. Sorry to ask too many questions. I'm new to regex concepts. now only started learning. Your inputs helped me a lot. don't mistake me. Will try my best or post a new question. Please assist. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ wiktot , I tried my best in different ways, i can't make it. Please help. I need to read the SSN based on Tags and also different format and before and after Tags reading. also created a new post.

Comment: `@wiktor` When i add `[^+]` to exclude the first digit in this regex `(?<!\d|\d[.\s-])(?:[^+]\d{3}(?=([.\s-]?))\1?\d{2}\1?\d{4})(?![.\s-]?\d)` it works as expected.... but it matches if zero is first digit even the format is wrong. Please assist. 0123-45-6789

Comment: @Sadu `[^+]` matches any char other than a `+` char. It does not exclude the first digit.

Comment: correct, I need to exclude number appended with `+` from the below input  current regex  `(?<!\d|\d[.\s-])(?:\d{3}(?=([.\s-]?))\1?\d{2}\1?\d{4})(?![.\s-]?\d)`  ... `Input :  My no:  0123-45-6789  and mobile  +123 45 2345 ` . .. When i try adding `[^+]` i can eliminate the phone number but it capture the other no 0123-45-6789. Which is wrong.

Comment: @Sadu Then simply add `(?<!\+)` at the pattern start.